# BigQuery: DELETE all rows from a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am just a bit confused about delete function in BigQuery. I have a BigQuery table that has set _PARTITIONTIME. Everyday, I need to upload a CSV to this BQ table. Since that CSV may add rows everyday (or maybe not), I want to delete all rows before I insert the values to the target BigQuery table. Which method should I use? I am not sure what _PARTITIONTIME is used for in this case. Thanks

Method 1:

```
DELETE FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE true;
```

Method 2:

```
target_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #ex. 2023-07-26
DELETE FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = '{target_date}'
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE` is going to be significantly faster than `DELETE`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered uploading the CSV to a Google Sheet, then creating a table based on that Google Sheet?

Any time you want to update the table, you just update the Google Sheet using the data from your CSV.

Every time you query the BigQuery table, it'd read directly from the Google Sheet. This way, you're not dealing with deleting rows.